# Column wraps when browser width is expanded

Tags: html, css

I have a two-column section on a web page. When I increase the width of the browser window (using Chrome) the second column wraps to the next row. How do I stop it from wrapping?

The code looks like this:

```
<section class="classname">
       <div class="col span_1_of_2">
             <h3>text</h3>
             <p class="classname">text</p>
             <ul class="classname">
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
                    <li>text</li>
             </ul>
             <p class="classname">text</p>         
        </div>  

        <div class="col span_1_of_2">
              <h3>text</h3>
              <p class="classname">text</p>
              <ul class="classname">
                     <li>text</li>
                     <li>text</li>
                     <li>text</li>
                     <li>text</li>
                     <li>text</li>
                     <li>text</li>    
              </ul>
              <p class="classname">text</p>     
        </div>
</section>
```

There is a similar section at the bottom of the page, also two columns, but using `<blockquote>`. The second column does not wrap there.

Here is the CSS:

```
/* columns */

.border {
    font-size: 80%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

.contactcolumn {
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 50px
    margin-right: 10px;
        }

.contactcolumn li{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, not the entire file. Just what's relevant. Don't make us sift. :)

Comment: I don't see your column classes in there anyway.

Comment: New here. Sorry. I'll fix that.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you are. We can't help unless we can see what you see. Div elements are full-width by default, so something's acting on them if they're inline-block at some screen widths. Use your browser's document inspector and find out what. Otherwise there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: To demonstrate the point, [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hzcqrLo2/) doesn't show the behavior you describe. The divs are full-width and stacked for all screen sizes.

Comment: My guess (based on those column classes) is that you're working in some frontend layout framework or library. Maybe check what .css files are being loaded into your page.